# Stargazer tables directly into pdf tables not showing up

Tags: r, r-markdown, stargazer

I have the following R Markdown document. I am trying to render regression output tables directly into pdf, but the tables don't show up. I have tried `type = 'latex'` instead of  `type = 'html'`, but no difference.

I know that I can copy-paste the latex code from the console, but that is really cumbersome. Any other solution to this?

````
```
---
title: "title"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(stargazer)
library(plm)
```
```{r data, echo=FALSE, include=FALSE}
library(haven)
dat <- read_dta("E:/CZ/CZ_fin_distress/CZ_all_2015_2018_small_final.dta")
library(dplyr)
dat <- dat %>% 
  rename(
    log_avgprice = lamt,
    log_localprice = lsamt, 
    negNPM = cat2,
    lagged_negNPM = lcat
    )
dat <- dat[dat$ptype<3,]
```
```{r prices, echo=FALSE, include=FALSE, results="asis"}
ma  <-  plm(log_avgprice ~ negNPM, index=c("id", "year"), model="within", data=dat)
mb  <-  plm(log_localprice ~ negNPM, index=c("id", "year"), model="within" , data=dat)
mc  <-  plm(log_avgprice ~ lagged_negNPM, index=c("id", "year"), model="within", data=dat)
md  <-  plm(log_localprice ~ lagged_negNPM, index=c("id", "year"), model="within", data=dat)


stargazer(ma, mb, mc, md, title = "Logged claim amount", type = 'html')
```
````

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake:  `include=FALSE` and `results="asis"` cancel each other out. It works now after eliminating  `include=FALSE`.